# Event handlers in separate document

Tags: javascript

I got this HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.commercial.com" onclick="confirmLeave()" target="_blank">
```

and

```
<IMG SRC="folder/picture_small.jpg" alt="Desrciption" onClick="view(this);">
```

And then I got a seperate Javascript document connected to this with this JS code:

```
  function confirmLeave()
  {
     if(confirm("Do you want to leave my page??")) {
      return true;
    } else {
      if(window.event) {
        window.event.returnValue = false;
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
```

and

```
function view(img) {
   imgsrc = img.src.split("_")[0] + "_big.jpg";
   viewwin = window.open(imgsrc,'viewwin', "width=790,height=444,location=0");  
  viewwin.focus();  
}
```

I would like to move my event handlers into my javascript document as well so I don't need the onClick command in my HTML. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to use jQuery, then you can use [jQuery events](http://api.jquery.com/category/Events/) which will let you attach event handlers for various events, including [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

HTML...

```
<div id="target">
  Click here
</div>
```

Separate JavaScript file...

```
$("#target").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

Comment: I'd like to do it without jQuery

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple:

```
document.getElementById("mylinkid").onclick = confirmLeave;
```

BTW, you should give a (modern) JavaScript library a look.

Comment: If I understand this right I add an id to my links:
    <a href="http://www.commercial.com" id"=link" target="_blank">

and then I add 

    document.getElementById("link").onclick = confirmLeave; 

into my JS document. If that is the way, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: `id"=link"` are you sure about that? NB: the element has to exist when the JS is executed in order to work (aka put the JS at the end of the document).